# Android app actions: voice/text invocation

Tags: android, app-actions

for quite some time now I'm facing troubles working with app actions. As long as I fire it from App Actions Test Tool everything works well. As soon as I try to launch it via google assistant (either text or voice) all I get is search results. Below actions.xml.

```
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />
        
        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
    </action>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.CREATE_THING">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://deeplink{?name}" >
            <parameter-mapping urlParameter="name" intentParameter="thing.name" />
        </fulfillment>
        
        <parameter name="thing.name">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="nameEntitySet"/>
        </parameter>
    </action>



    <entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
        <entity url="https://deeplink/one" name="featureParam_one" alternateName="@array/featureParam_one_synonyms"/>
        <entity url="https://deeplink/two" name="featureParam_two" alternateName="@array/featureParam_two_synonyms"/>
    </entity-set>

    <entity-set entitySetId="nameEntitySet">
        <entity identifier="ID_ONE" name="name_one" alternateName="@array/name_one_synonyms"/>
        <entity identifier="ID_TWO" name="name_two" alternateName="@array/name_two_synonyms"/>
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

I changed language in google assistant settings, in device settings and changed the timezone all for en-US. Seems like there's no config issues since it works through AATT. I think I tried almost all possibilities in terms of wording. I also tried uploading build through internal release - same result.
Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Could you able to get it working on real device.

Comment: No, all voice/text invocation I tried on real device, still no luck.

Comment: @Diego Can you help us with this? Is this a Google Assistant issue or its something we are missing from our end?

Comment: Make sure to run [this checklist](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/troubleshoot#test_5) to verify that you cover all your bases. If the problem persists, let me know.

Comment: @RobertDzieza hi did you get this resolved? if so how? thanks

Comment: @dewijones92 Unluckily no, I made some of it to work for a while but then it stopped again. I didn't really make any code changes in the meantime. And since I was not able to have any consistency here this project is temporary on hold.

Comment: @RobertDzieza after loads of time I am finally getting somewhere. Hopefully this helps you. The tablet i was only works with app actions for apps released on the play store. It does not work for apps in dev mode - unless you are invoking them from the android test (not voice). These actions (with voice) work fine on my phone tho. So I am doing development on my phone instead.

Comment: @dewijones92 thanks! I should give it a try someday ;)

Comment: @RobertDzieza I want to wean myself off third party shareholders' propriety tech. It could easily be switched off at at the whim of the shareholders. I am looking into mozilla deepspeech